# Why do the co-ordinates change to lat lon when making WFS-T request instead of lon lat

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, wfs-t

This is my code to make a a WFS-T insert transaction

```js
    let feature_to_send = new ol.Feature({geom: commentSelector.getFeatures().item(0).getGeometry().clone().transform('EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326')})
    feature_to_send.setProperties({
        'geocoder_id': 'abcd',
        'geocoder_name': 'xyz',
        'comment': $("#comment-text").val()
    })

    const transaction = new ol.format.WFS().writeTransaction(
        [feature_to_send], //insert
        null, //update
        null, //delete
        new ol.format.GML({
            version: "1.1.0",
            srsName: 'EPSG:4326',
            featureNS: "https://geoserver.xyz.com/abc",
            featureType: "geocoder_comments",
            typename: "geocoder_comments",
        }))

    const body = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(transaction);
```

This is what the transaction looks like. The coordinates are in lat lon but the geoserver is expecting it to be in lon lat. How do I change the coordinates to lon lat?

```xml
<Transaction
    xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" service="WFS" version="1.1.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd">
    <Insert>
        <geocoder_comments
            xmlns="https://geoserver.xyz.com/abc">
            <geom>
                <Point
                    xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/gml" srsName="EPSG:4326">
                    <pos srsDimension="2">37.864274435519434 -75.5042719458545</pos>
                </Point>
            </geom>
            <geocoder_id>abcd</geocoder_id>
            <geocoder_name>xyz</geocoder_name>
            <comment>sgfsda</comment>
        </geocoder_comments>
    </Insert>
</Transaction>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just removed this line from the GML and it works correctly now

```js
srsName: 'EPSG:4326'
```

Comment: Read https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wfs/axis_order.html and try if using  `srsName: 'urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326'` has the same effect.

Comment: when in doubt try to use a well defined projection instead of 4326 :-)

Answer (score 1):

To swap the feature geometry coordinates you can use `.applyTransform` geometry method:

```
feature_to_send.getGeometry().applyTransform(function (coords, coords2, stride) {
  for (var j = 0; j < coords.length; j += stride) {
    var y = coords[j];
    var x = coords[j + 1];
    coords[j] = x;
    coords[j + 1] = y;
  }
});
```